# Caching an object to a file in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently retrieving data from firestore and saving the retrieved data to a list, the list is used to create a cache file in the internal storage. When the app is started I check for network, and if there is no network I use the data from the cache to populate a recyclerview. This works fine, however I would like to perform CRUD operations while offline and I struggle to find a way to accomplish this.

This is the code when retrieving data from firestore and calling to create a cache file.

```
override fun getFromFirestore(context: Context, callback: (MutableList<PostFirestore>) -> Unit) {
    db.firestoreSettings = settings
    val notesList = mutableListOf<PostFirestore>()
    try {
        db.collection("DiaryInputs")
                .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                    notesList.clear()

                    if (snapshot != null && !snapshot.isEmpty) {
                        for (doc in snapshot.documents) {
                            val note = doc.toObject(PostFirestore::class.java)
                            notesList.add(note!!)
                        }
                        cacheHelper.createCachedFile(context, notesList)
                        callback(notesList)

                    } else {
                        //Refreshing the RV and cache if firestore is empty.
                        cacheHelper.deleteCachedFile(context)
                        callback(notesList)
                    }
                }
    } catch (e: Exception){
        Log.d(TAG, "Failure", e)
    }

}
```

This is how the creation of the cache file is made:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
override fun createCachedFile(context: Context, notesList: MutableList<PostFirestore>) {


    val outputFile = File(context.cacheDir, "cache").toString() + ".tmp"

    val out: ObjectOutput = ObjectOutputStream(
            FileOutputStream(
                    File(outputFile)
            )
    )
    out.writeObject(notesList)
    out.close()
}
```

This is the dataclass PostFirestore

```
class PostFirestore: Serializable {

var id: String? = null
var diaryInput: String? = null
var temp: String? = null
var creationDate: String? = null

constructor() {}

constructor(id: String, diaryInput: String, temp: String, creationDate: String) {
    this.id = id
    this.diaryInput = diaryInput
    this.temp = temp
    this.creationDate = creationDate

}
```

}

What should I do to be able to add something to the cached file "cache.tmp" instead of overwriting it ? And possibly how to edit/delete something in the list that is stored in the cached file?

Comment: Firestore handles offline behavior automatically. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: Yes I know. I still want to do this in learning purposes.

Comment: OK. I wrote a quick overview below. Beyond that it's hard to give you a concrete answer, as the problem is either rather broad - or you have a more concrete question that is not clear to me from the post.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore handles offline read and writes automatically. See its documentation on [handling read and writes while offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).

If you don't want to depend on that, you'll have to replicate it in your own persistence layer. This includes (but may not be limited to):

1. Keeping a list of pending writes, that you send to the server-side database when the connection is restored.
2. Return the up-to-date data for local reads, meaning you merge the data from the local cache with any pending writes of that same data.
3. Resolve any conflicts that may happen when the connection is restored. So you'll either update your local cache at this point, or not, and remove the item from the list of pending writes.

There are probably many more steps, depending on your scenario. If you get stuck on a specific step, I recommend posting back with a new question with concrete details about that step.